# In a multi-master kubernetes cluster, do only one master schedule and are the other masters in a standby mode?

Tags: kubernetes

In a multi-master kubernetes cluster, do only one master schedule and are the other masters in a standby mode? Does all the masters coordinate and schedule pods and etc?

Answer (score 1):

That's mostly correct; one can see that process by looking at the logs of all the `controller-manager` Pods and observing:

> I1021 00:09:49.283273       1 leaderelection.go:243] attempting to acquire leader lease  kube-system/kube-controller-manager...

in some of them, and more "working" messages in just one of them:

> I1021 02:12:51.779698       1 cleaner.go:181] Cleaning CSR "csr-rf8vh" as it is more than 1h0m0s old and approved.

I say "mostly correct" because to the best of my knowledge all `apiserver` Pods are actively doing work -- or at the very least they service HTTPS traffic and emit Audit logs -- but the rest of the HA components use that leader lease pattern

As for your 2nd question

> Does all the masters coordinate and schedule pods and etc?

no, that's the job of the `scheduler` Pods, which, again, use that leader lease pattern in order to avoid competing scheduling decisions